# Список с вложенными кортежами в строку

Tags: python, строки, list, tuple

У меня имеется список с вложенными кортежами:

```
items = [(1, 'data1', 'data1.1'), (2, 'data2', 'data2.2') ... ]
```

Я хочу сделать из него строку:

```
text = '1 data1 data1.1\n 2 data2 data2.2\n'
```

Не могу понять как это сделать, хотел через цикл `for`, но получаю строку из последнего кортежа.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, в одну строку:

```
items = [(1, 'data1', 'data1.1'), (2, 'data2', 'data2.2')]

text = '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in items)
print(text)
```

---

Более многострочный вид (добавляет лишний '\n'):

```
text = ''
for i, a, b in items:
    text += str(i) + ' ' + a + ' ' + b + '\n'

print(text)
```

Более многострочный вид версия с `format` и `f-строками` (добавляет лишний '\n'):

```
text = ''
for i, a, b in items:
    text += '{} {} {}\n'.format(i, a, b)
    # Или так:
    text += f'{i} {a} {b}\n'

print(text)
```

Более многострочный вид версия с `join` и `map` (добавляет лишний '\n'):

```
text = ''
for x in items:
    text += ' '.join(map(str, x)) + '\n'

print(text)
```

Более многострочный вид версия `join`, `map` и `f-строками` (добавляет лишний '\n'):

```
text = ''
for x in items:
    text += f'{" ".join(map(str, x))}\n'

print(text)
```

---

**PS.**

`map(str, x)` – это выражение используется для приведения всех частей коллекции в строку, т.к. `join` работает только с строками. Т.е. `(1, 'data1', 'data1.1')` станет `('1', 'data1', 'data1.1')`

**PPS.**

Варианты с конкатенацией строки выглядят привычно и просто, но не являются эффективными для огромного количества строк из-за того, что строка в питоне неизменяемый объект, поэтому при сложении будет создана новая строка.

Эффективно будет через добавление элементов в список и последующем создании строки через `join`:

```
parts = []
for x in items:
    parts.append(' '.join(map(str, x)))

text = '\n'.join(parts)
print(text)
```

**PPPS.**

Все предложенные многострочные варианты прекрасно представляются в однострочном виде.

Например переписал код из **PPS**:

```
text = '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in items)
print(text)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы очень подробно расписали, опробую все варианты для большего понимания. Спасибо!